# Angular 2 Reactive Forms : How to bind to @Input?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have a table that on click of a link within a row, a modal pops up that will show a form where you can edit the information of that table.

I am trying to use a Reactive Forms approach with this form, but I am having trouble figuring out how to bind to  the @Input for my modal, which is the information of the row selected.

Here is an example of things I've tried:

```
@Input() row;

form : FormGroup


constructor(rowModalService : RowModalService, fb : FormBuilder, public activeModal : NgbActiveModal) {

    this.form = fb.group({
        name : [''],

    })


}
```

I attempted to initialize the value of name to an empty string and then find a valid lifecycle hook that will be able to update the value when my row input is not undefined, but I cannot find any lifecycle hooks that allow this.

Here is what I tried:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.form.controls['name'].setValue(this.row.name);

}
```

Any help as to the best way to do this would be appreciated. I cannot find a way to do this without a template-driven approach.

Comment: What lifecycle hooks did you try? `ngOnChanges` is so obvious here... See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-class.html

Comment: I thought this worked in the beginning, but it appears my ngOnChanges event is not being fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. It actually had nothing to do with the Reactive Forms approach itself, rather I forgot to change the name of the input parameter I was passing.

You are able to bind your controls to your input on init as detailed in my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few binding methods you can use .

For both way bindings , you can use [(ngModule)]=''.. i suggest that you go to angular.io to refer the tutorials if youre beginner .

Hope that helps :)